# Use Javascript if statement to show or hide a div

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to javascript and I am trying to create a simple if/else statement that will display a different divs.

```
<script>
   if (window.FileReader && Modernizr.draganddrop){
      alert("Your browser supports drag and drop!!");
      document.getElementById(no).style.display = 'none';
   }else{
      alert("Sorry, browser does not support drag and drop!");
      document.getElementById(yes).style.display = 'none';
   }
</script>
```

And then, in the body

```
<div id="yes">Drag and drop yes</div>

<div id="no">Drag and drop no</div>
```

Although the modernizr works just fine the script displays both divs

Any help will be greatfully received

Comment: You would be much better off using JQuery for this purpose.

Comment: Why would you use JQuery just for that?

Comment: `yes` and `no` should be strings and not variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script runs before the elements exist. Use the `load` event so that the code runs after the page has loaded completely:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   if (window.FileReader && Modernizr.draganddrop){
      alert("Your browser supports drag and drop!!");
      document.getElementById('no').style.display = 'none';
   }else{
      alert("Sorry, browser does not support drag and drop!");
      document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'none';
   }
};
</script>
```

Also, as Evan spotted, you are using `no` and `yes` rather than the strings `'no'` and `'yes'`.

Comment: This did the job perfectly thanks!  As soon as it lets me I'll accept this as the answer

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that getElementById expects a string, as far as I can see you haven't declared yes/no.

```
if (window.FileReader && Modernizr.draganddrop) {
    alert("Your browser supports drag and drop!!");
    document.getElementById('no').style.display = 'none';
} else {
    alert("Sorry, browser does not support drag and drop!");
    document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Thanks or your answer, however, as Guffa pointed out it did need to use the load event